# Using Reactive Extensions in an Asynchronious Way

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive

I am new to Reactive Extensions, I have the requirement to consume `PairCollection<IPointCloud>` which are fed into a service which performs a very expensive multi-threaded process but has limited concurrency (which I base on the number of machine cores). The process of getting the `PairCollection<IPointCloud>` objects is itself expensive as there are many, but can be done in parallel with no thread restriction so I have have decided to use ReactiveExtensions (why not) for this.

I have setup a LinqPAD example which simulates what I want, however, there are a few aspects of what I have done that do not feel right. I have started a `Task` to ensure the observable subscriptions do not block, however, I would like to do this using another Observable subscription, but one that is asynchronious, I would like some advice to ensure that

1. What I have done so far is correct?
2. How can I replace the Task.Run in the Main method with some form of async IObservable that does not block?
3. Is the method is use for cancellation support correct?

The pseudo data files that I read from "C:\Data" are available from here https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuCd_PcRnNWpn3qhr0MskrbhEoC2?e=M6d1zo.

```
void Main()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        int index = 0;
        var pairCollectionProducer = PairCollectionProducer(CancellationToken.None);

        pairCollectionProducer.Subscribe(cp =>
        {
            // Now run expensive process using pair collection. 
            // _pointCloudMergingService.Merge(cp);
            Console.WriteLine($"PairCollection count = {cp.Count:N0}, Index = {index++:N0}");
        }, 
        ex =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
        },
        () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("COMPLETED");
        });
    });
    Console.WriteLine("LAST LINE");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public IObservable<PairCollection<IPointCloud>> PairCollectionProducer(CancellationToken token)
{
    return Observable.Create<PairCollection<IPointCloud>>(
        observer =>
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(
                Utils.GetFileBatches(@"C:\Data"),
                (fileBatch) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{fileBatch[0]} file loop");

                if (fileBatch[0] == @"C:\Data\bb.0000.exr")
                    Thread.Sleep(200);

                var producer = RawDepthMapsProducer(fileBatch[0], token);

                int index = 0;
                ConcurrentBag<IPointCloud> bag = new ConcurrentBag<IPointCloud>();
                IDisposable subscriber = producer.Subscribe(rawDepthMap =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(50);
                    bag.Add(new PointCloud() { Index = index++ });
                }, 
                ex => { }, 
                () =>
                {
                    PointCloudPartitioningService ps = new PointCloudPartitioningService();
                    observer.OnNext(ps.Partition(bag.ToList()));
                });
            });
            observer.OnCompleted();
            return () => { };
        });
}

public IObservable<RawDepthMap> RawDepthMapsProducer(string filePath, CancellationToken token)
{
    return Observable.Create<RawDepthMap>(
        observer =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                Console.WriteLine($"filePath = {filePath}, i = {i:N0}");
                observer.OnNext(new RawDepthMap() { Height = i, Width = 1 });
            }
            observer.OnCompleted();
            return () => { };
        });
}

public interface IPointCloud
{
    Vertex[] Vertices { get; set; }

    bool ContainsNormals { get; }

    int? Index { get; set; }
}

public class PointCloud : IPointCloud
{
    public PointCloud() { }

    public PointCloud(Vertex[] vertices)
    {
        Vertices = vertices;
    }

    public Vertex[] Vertices { get; set; }

    public bool ContainsNormals => Vertices.Any(v =>
        v.Normal.X != 0.0f ||
        v.Normal.Y != 0.0f ||
        v.Normal.Z != 0.0f);

    public int? Index { get; set; }
}

public struct Vertex
{
    public Vertex(Vector3 point, Vector3 normal)
    {
        Point = point;
        Normal = normal;
    }
    public Vertex(Vector3 point)
        : this(point, new Vector3()) { }

    public Vector3 Point;
    public Vector3 Normal;
}

public class PairCollection<T> where T : class
{
    public PairCollection()
    {
        Partitions = new List<IndexedPair<T>>();
        Last = null;
    }

    public List<T> Flatten()
    {
        List<T> l = new List<T>();
        foreach (var it in Partitions)
        {
            l.Add(it.Pair.Item1);
            l.Add(it.Pair.Item2);
        }
        if (Last != null)
            l.Add(Last);

        return l;
    }

    public IList<IndexedPair<T>> Partitions { get; set; }

    public T Last { get; set; }

    public int Count { get { return Partitions.Count * 2 + (Last != null ? 1 : 0); } }
}

public class IndexedPair<T>
{
    public IndexedPair(int index, T item1, T item2)
        : this(index, new Tuple<T, T>(item1, item2)) { }

    public IndexedPair(int index, Tuple<T, T> tuple)
    {
        Index = index;
        Pair = tuple;
    }

    public int Index { get; set; }

    public Tuple<T, T> Pair { get; set; }
}

public class RawDepthMap
{
    public string Source { get; set; }

    public List<double> DepthMapArray { get; set; }

    public int Height { get; set; }

    public int Width { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string source = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Source) ? Source : "N/A";
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder($"RawDepthMap: Source \"{source}\"");
        if (DepthMapArray != null)
            builder.Append($", Array size {DepthMapArray:N0}");

        builder.Append($", Width {Width:N0}, Height {Height:N0}");
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}

public interface IPartitioningService<T> where T : class
{
    PairCollection<T> Partition(IList<T> itemList);
}

public class PointCloudPartitioningService : PartitioningServiceBase<IPointCloud>
{
    public override PairCollection<IPointCloud> Partition(IList<IPointCloud> pointCloudCollection)
    {
        if (pointCloudCollection == null || pointCloudCollection.Count < 2)
            throw new ArgumentException("Point cloud collection cannot be null or less than 2");

        if (pointCloudCollection.Any(pc => pc.Index == null))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("All point clouds must be indexed");

        List<IPointCloud> orderedPointClouds = pointCloudCollection
            .OrderBy(f => (int)f.Index)
            .ToList();

        return PartitioningCore(orderedPointClouds);
    }
}

public abstract class PartitioningServiceBase<T> : IPartitioningService<T> where T : class
{
    public abstract PairCollection<T> Partition(IList<T> itemList);

    protected PairCollection<T> PartitioningCore(IList<T> itemList)
    {
        int index = 0;
        PairCollection<T> partitionedCollection = new PairCollection<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < itemList.Count; i += 2)
        {
            if (i + 1 >= itemList.Count)
                break;

            IndexedPair<T> it = new IndexedPair<T>(
                index++, itemList[i], itemList[i + 1]);
            partitionedCollection.Partitions.Add(it);
        }

        if (itemList.Count % 2 != 0)
            partitionedCollection.Last = itemList.Last();

        return partitionedCollection;
    }
}

public static class Utils
{
    public static List<List<string>> GetFileBatches(string directory)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
            throw new IOException($"Directory \"{directory}\" does not exist");

        var fileInfoCollection = Directory.GetFiles(directory).Select(f => new FileInfo(f));
        if (fileInfoCollection.Any(fi => !DepthMapSourceMappings.SupportedDepthMapSourceTypes.ContainsKey(Path.GetExtension(fi.Name))))
        {
            string tmp = String.Join(", ", DepthMapSourceMappings.SupportedDepthMapSourceTypes.Select(kvp => kvp.Key));
            throw new IOException($"Only source files of type ({tmp.Trim()}) are currently supported");
        }

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\w+");
        return fileInfoCollection
            .GroupBy(fi => regex.Match(fi.Name).ToString())
            .Select(group => group.Select(fi => fi.FullName).ToList())
            .ToList();
    }
}

public enum DepthMapSourceType
{
    Exr
};

public static class DepthMapSourceMappings
{
    public static Dictionary<string, DepthMapSourceType> SupportedDepthMapSourceTypes { get; } =
        new Dictionary<string, DepthMapSourceType>()
    {
                { ".exr", DepthMapSourceType.Exr }
    };
}
```

Comment: Anyway you can make this less abstract?  There are thread sleeps.  I assume to account for work? Rx isn't usually used for fan out work unless you are using Tasks. What might work better is TPL Data Flow and creating a data flow mesh which would also help with back pressure.  If processing the file take a long time do you really want to create and queue up unlimited objects of files? I have more questions but without more concrete sample it's hard to know what's right.  For Ex why is RawDepthMapsProducer another observable create with a loop of 10 instead of just .Select or.SelectMany?

Comment: The thread sleeps are to simulate work, yes. The process that creates the `IPointCloud`s is relatively inexpensive and I want this process to be done using max parrallelisation. Likewise with RawDepthMap production. However, the processing in the main method will be very expensive and the threading is throttled using a limited concurrency TaskScheduler. I think this is a good candidate for the user of Rx. I have decided I need to await the Parrallel.ForEach so it does not fire the OnCompleted right away, so I am going to swap this out for an array of Tasks and await all of these.

Comment: I'll struggle to make this less abstract unless I re-write all of the code using primitive types.

Answer (score 1):

GetFileBatches is enumerating fileInfoCollection twice.  One for Any and once for groupby.

By default Rx runs same thread.  You could test this by logging Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId and seeing the values. The RawDepthMapsProducer isn't adding anything and just adding over head since its all on the same thread.   You can read more [here](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html).  Right now it's just the code inside the Parallel.ForEach that is using different threads, but the Observable inside are using the same thread.

Rx running by default on the same thread is why the Task.Run needed to be there to get it off the main thread.  ObserveOn would be a more Rx option or using SelectMany for Tasks.

Hard to give more feedback with this so much abstracted and if you can use Task or not.  You could switch to the ObserveOn to use ThreadPool but this might cause too much back pressure.